# 404 page errors with custom post type pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

This is my events template page in wordpress that displays 2 events at a time, but when you click on the previous posts link to show older event posts I keep getting this 404 page error in my custom post type. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my complete code on my template page:

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Events Page
*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="wrapper">  

    <section id="main-content">

        <div class="signup">
            <a href="#">Sign up for our mailing list</a>
        </div>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <article>
                <?php the_content(); ?> 
            </article>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <section id="event-listings">

            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'events',
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
                );      

                $global_posts_query = new WP_Query($args);
            ?>

            <?php if ($global_posts_query->have_posts()) : while ($global_posts_query->have_posts()) : $global_posts_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <article class="post">
                        <div class="date">
                            <p><?php the_field('date'); ?><br><span class="year"><?php the_field('year'); ?></span></p>
                        </div>              

                        <h2><?php the_field('headline'); ?></h2>

                        <p class="location"><?php the_field('location'); ?> &hearts; <?php the_field('time'); ?></p>

                        <p class="coordinator">Created by: <span class="name"><?php the_field('author'); ?> on <time datetime="<?php echo date(DATE_W3C); ?>" pubdate class="updated"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time></span></p>

                        <p class="about-content"><?php the_field('about'); ?></p>
                    </article>  

            <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                <p>No events posted at this time.</p>   

            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $global_posts_query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
                <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;', $global_posts_query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
            </div>              

        </section>                          

    </section><!--End Main Content-->

</div><!--End Wrapper-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: once again submit the permalink....it not update with custom post tag

Comment: I don't understand! What do you mean, submit the permalink?

Comment: sometimes htaccess not regonize custom post type...so once again submit hte permalink, it works

Comment: Sorry Tamil, but I don't understand what you mean by submit the permalink.

Comment: @davidz Google *wordpress permalink* and click the first link.

Comment: Hello, when I changed the permalink setting to Default it worked! But when I changed it back to the Day and Name setting I get the 404 error again.